# How to Vectorize and Unvectorize in Excel?

Tags: excel, matrix

Suppose an Excel file has vectorized 2-by-2 symmetric matrices line by line as follows:

| line | A: element11 | B: element22 | C: element12=element21 | D: DETERMINANT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 35 |
| 3 | 11 | 13 | 0 | 143 |
| … | … | … | … | … |

Thus, the first value of DETERMINANT column can be computed from a matrix {2 0,0 3}, the second value can be from a matrix {5 0,0 7}, and so on. Instead of reshaping the A1:C1 values, the D1 value can be directly computed via `=MDETERM(IF(A1:B1=TRANSPOSE(A1:B1),A1:B1,C1))` because `IF` can actually reshape the A1:C1 values to the diagonal matrix of interest.

The point is that, in Excel, matrix functions such as `MDETERM` directly require matrices, while the matrices in the data are stored row by row after vectorization. Unfortunately, the `IF` solution above can only reshape 2-by-2 symmetric matrices and handle neither asymmetric matrices nor matrices with more than two off-diagonal elements. Do we have any other solutions more general than the illustrated `IF` approach to unvectorize matrices?

In addition, I am also interested in vectorizing matrices in Excel as well; for example, the matrix in A1:C1 can be reshaped, inverted, and then restored in the D1:G1 area. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have meant

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1:B1)=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:B1)),A1:B1,C1)
```

But you can certainly expand on this idea. Suppose you have the diagonal elements of a symmetric 4X4 matrix in A1:D1 and the off-diagonal elements in E1:J1.

Then you could use

```
=IF(ROW(A1:D4)=COLUMN(A1:D4),INDEX(A1:J1,ROW(A1:D4)),
IF(ROW(A1:D4)<COLUMN(A1:D4),INDEX(E1:J1,(ROW(A1:D4)-1)*4+COLUMN(A1:D4)-ROW(A1:D4)*(ROW(A1:D4)+1)/2),
INDEX(E1:J1,(COLUMN(A1:D4)-1)*4+ROW(A1:D4)-COLUMN(A1:D4)*(COLUMN(A1:D4)+1)/2)))
```

[image]

A bit more general with Excel 365 Let function:

```
=LET(N,4,mat,A1:INDEX(A1:Z26,N,N),
IF(ROW(mat)=COLUMN(mat),
INDEX(1:1,ROW(mat)),
IF(ROW(mat)<COLUMN(mat),
INDEX(1:1,(ROW(mat)-1)*N+COLUMN(mat)-ROW(mat)*(ROW(mat)+1)/2+N),
INDEX(1:1,(COLUMN(mat)-1)*N+ROW(mat)-COLUMN(mat)*(COLUMN(mat)+1)/2+N))))
```